# Prevent JSON.parse removing a backslash and the following letter?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Consider the following string:

```
text = '{"section": "\main" }'
```

If I apply JSON.parse to this I obtain the data

> {section: "ain"}

I want to parse a string into a Javascript variable using JSON.parse but I don't want it to perform modifications due to backslashes.

So there a setting I can use so that JSON.parse doesn't remove the backslash and the letter 'm', and instead gives me the data

> {section: "\main"}

Anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: `JSON.parse` doesn't change anything in the string. If you need a backslash in a string, escape it with another backslash.

Comment: The string `'text = {"section": "\main" }'` is anything but, not JSON. If you feed that to `JSON.parse`, all bets are off.

Comment: I am working with Latex strings which require backslashes. At the moment I have to use two backslashes for all Latex commands, eg. $\\int_D G(x,y)f(y)dy$. This is because JSON.parse strips the first one. If I could prevent JSON.parse from interacting with the backslash I could just write standard Latex, eg. $\int_D G(x,y)f(y)dy$

Comment: @Tomalak I forgot to include the single commas outside the brackets..I've edited them into my post now.

Comment: The string `'{"section": "\main" }'` resembles JSON, but the escape sequence `\m` is invalid, so the entire string is invalid. Whatever generates this string is broken and should be fixed. Don't try to fix it at the parsing end.

Comment: If you want to use a *\* char in a javascript string (or any other language) you have to escape this with the proper escape character, that in this case is *\*. I don't think your issue is with JSON.parse, rather it is with what you do with the value after that, as any time you use the string you lost a quotation. In the case you use as an example *\m* for the javascript intepeter is only one character.

Comment: Funny thing, when I test `JSON.parse('{"section": "\main" }')` on chrome's console the output is "main" not "ain"

Comment: @n0m4d I noticed that aswell. I've provided a simple solution for this, wich would take all "\ and change them into "\\\\ so it will have a backslash after JSON.parse

Comment: @J0N3X thanks for pointing that out, but in my case chrome's console doesn't strip away the "m" letter, contrary to what occurs to the SO. Try pasting that code into your chrome's console or another browser's, the output will still  be "main".

Comment: Odd as **** i say mon

Comment: Ok based I checked it in Chromes console and it turns out it is not the JSON.parse that caused the issue. It is the actual declaration of the string. Declaring text = '{"section": "\main" }' results in "{"section": "main" }". Is there any way of preventing the interpreter from treating the backslash as an escape character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got to replace all those single backslashes with 4 backslashes.

```
jsonString.replace('"\','"\\\\');
```

That should do the trick. No idea why 4 is needed, but that worked for me.

Comment: No, that will break the portions of the input string where the escaping is valid. Broken input cannot be fixed quite so easily at the parsing level.

Comment: Okay, so you want to escape and you dont want to escape. How clean is your data? And please see that it only changes "\ not \. @Tomalak

Comment: I'm not the OP. ;) Anyway, using `'"\'` does not help matters. The `{"section": "\main" }` is merely an example, it's certainly not the OP's entire input. Assuming that "every backslash after a double quote" needs extra escaping is not one bit better than assuming that "every backslash" needs extra escaping.

Comment: @Tomalak You are very true in this. Id like to know why op does even have backslashes in his data. He could replace it with another combination of marks to the replace later

Comment: Well, as I said. It's very difficult to fix broken data. Fixing the source of the broken data is *much* easier than trying to fix the mess at the consuming end.

Comment: Ok based I checked it in Chromes console and it turns out it is not the JSON.parse that caused the issue. It is the actual declaration of the string. Declaring text = '{"section": "\main" }' results in "{"section": "main" }". Is there any way of preventing the interpreter from treating the backslash as an escape character? –

Comment: The original post is confusing now that I've realised the issue is not what I thought it was. I have asked the proper question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957719/prevent-javascript-escaping-text