# Prevent Javascript escaping text?

Tags: javascript, json

Declaring

`text = '{"section": "\main" }'`

results in

> "{"section": "main" }"

Is there a way to prevent the Javascript interpreter from treating the backslash as an escape character and removing it?

I want to be able to declare "{"section": "\main" }" and keep the backslash in the output"

> "{"section": "\main" }"

Note: I realise that if I use two backslashes it will give me the desired output. But I don't want to use two backslashes as I have a lot of Latex code that I am including in a webpage and it is extremely awkward having to double escape everything. So is there a way to prevent Javascript escaping text?

Comment: Use a text editor to replace "\" with "\\" in your Latex code, it's not awkward at all.

Comment: Have the text in a div and read the div's innerText into a var if you do not want to escape @Mikey - yes I saw it wand removed my comment

Comment: As far as I know, JS can not do this.

Comment: Also called back tics in coding

Comment: @dandavis are you sure it's enough? From my tests in both FF and chrome, `\`\main\`` is escaped just like `"\main"`

Comment: @GOTO0 It certainly is awkward. I don't want to have to type an extra "\" for every single piece of Latex, these documents will have thousands of such commands. And replacing "\" with "\\" using a text editor is only going to lead to more hassle when I make updates as the existing "\\" will now become "\\\\" unless I go out of my way to avoid it which means more work. I just want to turn the backslash escaping off altogether as I don't need it.

Comment: @Kaiido:  yes; get the raw instead of the assignment

Comment: @dandavis, still not sure to get it... how would [`\`\\`\`==="\`"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Description)? I think you meant to use the `raw` property of the first function argument of tagged template literals, didn't you? (`function tag(str, ...values){
console.log(str.raw[0]);
}
tag\`\main\`;` will indeed work too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("latextstrings").innerText)
```

```html
<div id="latextstrings" style="display:none">
  {"section": "\main" }
  {"section": "\sub" }</div>
```

Comment: How are you gonna set the innerHTML?

Comment: So non dynamic. Probably fine to OP, even if then I would probably myself prefer a comment node than an hidden element.

Comment: _I have a lot of Latex code that I am including in a webpage_

Comment: Yep "probably fine to OP" I said, just before upvote. But his question is how to make js not escape text, so this is a server-side workaround, not a js one.

Comment: Sure  but I read it as "how to make unescaped latex strings available to JavaScript" for later use

Comment: Its a good idea but I have client side rendering. All my data (which includes the latex strings) is in a JSON file.

Answer (score 6):

In [supporting browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Browser_compatibility), you could use the [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) method like this :

```js
console.log(String.raw`\main`);
```

Comment: Are the back tics on their own enough? Cannot test this right now

Comment: @mplungjan good question, also saw this comment and on my way back to the keyboard to test this after dandavis comment.

Comment: @mplungjan So the answer is nope in FF : `'hello'+\`\main\``->`"hellomain"`, while ``'hello'+String.raw`\main`⁣⁣``⁣ correctly outputs `"hello\main"`. (ps: funny how I had to use backslashes in here to make ths comment ;-) )

Comment: The data is actually in a variable. Is it still possible to use String.raw with a variable instead of direct text?

Comment: @csss, as said by mplungjan on his answer's comment, "*Then* [your data is] *already escaped!*". If it's not, then JSON parser will throw you an SyntaxError : "bad escaped character ..."

Answer (score -1):

Just double-escape it, it's the simpliest

```
"\\main"
```